# como instalar matlib en MAC OS sierra

Tags: packages

Me muestra este mensaje

```
Error al cargar library(matlib)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Users/davidcademartorirosso/Library/R/4.0/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/Users/davidcademartorirosso/Library/R/4.0/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/davidcademartorirosso/Library/R/4.0/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘matlib’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: NULL
  error:    Loading rgl's DLL failed. 
    On MacOS, rgl depends on XQuartz, which you can download from xquartz.org.
```

Answer (score 0):

buenas como lo indica la doc oficial lo puede instalar asi:

```
sudo port install py36-pip
python3 -mpip install matplotlib
```

y cuando lo instales con este comando lo puedes verificar:

```
python3 -c 'import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__, matplotlib.__file__)'
```

te deberia salir algo asi:

> 3.0.0 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py

[docs](https://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html)

Comment: > sudo port install py36-pip
Error: unexpected symbol in "sudo port"
> python3 -mpip install matplotlib
Error: unexpected symbol in "python3 -mpip install"

Comment: Se produce el siguiente error. Mi sistema operativo es sierra 10.13

Comment: Se produce el siguiente error:> sudo port install py36-pip
Error: unexpected symbol in "sudo port"
> python3 -mpip install matplotlib
Error: unexpected symbol in "python3 -mpip install"

Comment: ya intentastes reinstalando python?